# UK Family visa sponsorship, employment contract details aren't fully accurate

Tags: visas, uk, proof-of-employment

I am sponsoring my wife's family visa application to come to the uk using my salary and employment details. My original employment contract signed back in Dec 2021 has a start date of the 21st Feb 2022 but I started work on the 14th Feb 2022 as I was ready to start working sooner than expected.

With the application, it asks for an employment start date which is the 14th Feb and I have a letter from my employer confirming that. My only concern is that they will reject the application as the date in the contract is different.

I've looked through the [appendix](https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/1039148/1.7_-_Financial_requirement.pdf) on financial requirements and it doesn't seem to give any details on differences between documents due to one being out of date.

My question is how should I address differences between documents in the application please?

Comment: You can simply explain it in a covering letter?

Comment: Thank you for your response, I was thinking I could write and sign a letter explaining the difference along with the email chain agreeing I could start earlier but wasn't sure if there was a different proper way to explain differences. If a cover letter is the best place then that's the way I'll go.